# Linking to boostrap's Javascript code prevents onclick event handler from running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, jquery-events

This simple [test page](http://pastebin.com/1YaDs1aY) is meant to display a link and pop up an alert if the user clicks on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- uncommenting the next line prevents the alert from showing up -->
    <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">  -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
          
        $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#show_more_link").click(function(e) {
            alert("on click running");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>   
</head>

<body>
    <a id="show_more_link" href="#">click here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Problem: uncommenting the line where Bootstrap's minified Javascript is included (line #10) breaks the onclick event:

- If that line is commented out, clicking on the link pops up an alert (as intended).
- If the line is uncommented, clicking on the link does nothing.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Your script isn't closed/is missing the closing `</script>` tag, that's why you get errors and your code breaks, you need to do it like this:

```
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```